# printf("%f",5/4) in C language returns 0.00000 unexpectedly

Tags: c, casting

it prints out 0.000000

I expected 1.2500000000

Why is it happening?

Answer (score 2):

You are doing integer division by `5/4` and trying to print the result in float. So the behavior is ambiguous. You can try this to get the desired result:

```
printf("%f",(float)5/4);
```